# Obtener lista de fuentes pysimplegui python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

necesito hacer un selector de tipografia en pysimplegui, usando python 3, como hago para obtener un lista con las fuentes instaladas en mi sistema?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente no hay ningún cuadro de diálogo / botón "Selector de Font". Hay un archivo, una carpeta, un calendario y un selector de color, pero no un selector de Font.

Podrías hacer algo así con otro paquete como tkfontchooser. No lo he intentado, pero algo así. Es posible acceder a la variable tk root con PSG. Se encuentra en `Window.Tkroot`. A continuación, puede utilizar esta variable para iniciar cuadros de diálogo usted mismo.

Debido a que no hay un diálogo de selección de fuente integrado en tkinter, debe crear uno de estos usted mismo. Hay un [programa de demostración](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Font_Previewer.py) en PySimpleGUI GitHub que muestra cómo obtener la lista de fuentes, previsualizándolas. Podrías extenderlo para convertirte en una ventana de elección de fuente.

[Puedes ver ese código ejecutándose aquí en repl.it](https://repl.it/@PySimpleGUI/Font-Previewer)

Este código le dará una lista de las fuentes disponibles:

```
from tkinter import fonts

layout [ ...... ]    
window = sg.Window('My new window', layout).Finalize()
fonts = list(font.families())
fonts.sort()
```

Comment: mira por favor [answer]. Podria poner algun ejemplo de lo que decis? si no, la respuesta solo parece un comentario

Comment: No veo cómo borrar mi respuesta. Quizás un moderador pueda borrarlo.

Comment: Los moderadores somos los que tenemos un diamante (como yo ;)) No te pedi que borraras tu respuesta (hay un boton eliminar al lado del de editar), si no que la completaras. Por ejemplo estas dando una forma de hacerlo, como seria el codigo de ello?

Comment: Muchas gracias Mike me sirvio mucho la respuesta, antes habia visto soluciones similares, pero como no hacian el root.destroy() me quedaba abierta una ventana que se llamaba root, es la primer vez que uso esto asi que no sabia como hacer para que no quede esa ventana

Comment: Edité mi respuesta para demostrar cómo puede obtener la lista de fuentes sin usar la variable raíz como lo mostraba anteriormente. Esta nueva forma requiere que primero hagas tu ventana y luego puedas obtener la lista de fuentes.